# Check all elements are different in the list in python

Tags: python

I have to find all list elements are equal.

I have used below code:

```
        all(x == list[0] for x in list)
```

Now I have to find all list values are different. Please help me how to achieve this.

```
     List = ['a', 'b', 'x', 'y']

     Expected Output: True

     List = ['a', 'a', 'x', 'y']

     Expected Output: False

     List = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']

     Expected Output: False
```

Tried below code:

```
 list = ["aa", "bb", "bb"] 
 len(set(list)) != 1 
 output:
 will result True.
 I am expecting False, reason bb is same elements repeated
```

Comment: @Aran-Fey, That is for to find out unique in list. That is i achieved it. I am looking for How to find all values are different in list

Comment: What's the difference between "unique" and "different"?

Comment: if the length of your list is the same as the length of all uniques in your list ... ` all(x == list[0] for x in list)` could also be expressed as `len(set(list)) == 1`   - and you should refrain from calling any variable ``list`, `set` or any other of the build-ins

Comment: @Aran-Fey I am confused.

Comment: @Patrick Artner,  if  list = ["aa", "bb", "bb"] .........len(set(list)) != 1 ...will return  True and I am expecting False

Comment: `len(set(item)) == len(item)`  if the lenght of your list is the same as the length of all unique elements of the list ... your list is unique to begin with... `len(set(list)) ==1` is:  all elements of your list are the same - which you solved by `all(x == list[0] for x in list)`. `len(set(list)) != 1` checks if the list is empty or contains at least 2 different things ...

Comment: @Sagar  if len(set(list)) != len(list) False else True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you have written `len(set(list)) != 1` which only works if all elements in list are same if you have two elements repeats for thousand of time then it will return length of set as two because it will have two unique elements.

So one way is that you check length of unique elements with original list if its same then function evaluates True otherwise False

```
def all_distinct(lis):
    return len(set(lis)) == len(lis)
```

`set(lis)` - creates set of element where all elements are unique (never repeated)
`len()` - returns length of set or list or string passed as argument.

```
In [8]: all_distinct(['a', 'a'])
Out[8]: False

In [9]: all_distinct(['a', 'a', 'x'])
Out[9]: False

In [11]: all_distinct(['a', 'b', 'x'])
Out[11]: True
```

You can also approach in different way as below (keeping record of occurances)

```
def get_occurrence(lis):
    td = {}
    for i in lis:
        td[i] = td.setdefault(i, 0) + 1
    return td

def all_distinct(lis):
    dict_ = get_occurrence(lis)  # this will return dict containing key as element and value of it's occurrence 
    return all(i==1 for i in dict_.values())
```

Comment: `set(lis)` does not sort at all - sets are unordered - see : https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset :  `A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects. `

Answer (score 3):

Use set filter the duplicates id same element then its length will be less that original list

```
def all_unique(item):
    return len(set(item)) == len(item)
```

## OUT

```
>>> all_unique(['a', 'b', 'x', 'y'])
True
>>> all_unique(['a', 'a', 'x', 'y'])
False
>>> all_unique(['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'])
False
>>>
```

Comment: I am looking to check all elements

Comment: use for loop and call this method